# google analytics is undefined a default value?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

This is what i send to Google Analytics:

```
// Default values?
var label = undefined;
var action = undefined;

// Assign some values
label = 'something';
action = 666;

// Send GA event
window._gaq.push(['_trackEvent','My Category', 'My Event Name', label, action]);
```

My question is: Am I right assigning default values as undefined as sometimes my label and action variables will not contain anything? Will event still be sent properly across all browsers?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Sent yes. Whether Google Analytics understand/likes it is another question. Maybe empty strings are better, but I don't know Google Analytics. Their API documentation should mention which values are possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't set them and send a 2 items array.

There are exemples in the official documentation : https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApi_gaq#_gaq.push

```
_gaq.push(['t2._setAccount', 'UA-65432-2']);
_gaq.push(['t2._setDomainName', 'foo.com']);
_gaq.push(['t2._trackPageview']);
```

Comment: easy to say but i dont want to have in my code IF (!label) ... do this and  another IF (!action) ... :/

Comment: You could encapsulate the `if` in a function to trim the array of its `undefined` values.